# Lightweight versioning system for standalone development

Tags: version-control

I develop a lot of prototypes while I am trying out stuff. I wish I could have a lightweight versioning system which would keep backup of these and make it easy for me to find them next time. It would also help me in keeping track of all the various techiniques I have tried for solving a particular problem.

I would like to know your suggestions on using the right tool for this Job.

**Update:** A simple google would have given me the names of all the version control apps and git be my preferred choice. But I would like to know which would be the lightest app for the job and why. I dont want a single repo to take GBs of space.

Comment: git !!! U dont need to setup a git server or something U can use it on a local repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git would be the efficient in handling space as thats their claim. Check the link below

https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitBenchmarks#Git.2C_Mercurial.2C_Bazaar_repository_size_benchmark

Answer (score 1):

A DVCS such as git or Mercurial will let you create a repo directly in the project directory that you can use to track and manipulate changes.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/).

It is quick to setup for each working copy/repository, and doesn't require a separate server.

Answer (score 1):

[BitBucket](http://bitbucket.org/) + [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) is a good combination.

> Bitbucket is a web-based hosting service for projects that use the Mercurial revision control system. Bitbucket offers both commercial plans and free accounts. Unusually - and possibly uniquely - for a project hosting service, as of September 2010, it offers free accounts with unlimited numbers of private repositories (which can have up to five users in the case of free accounts).

Answer (score 1):

Go for a DVCS like git or mercurial. I use the Tortoise Hg version of Mercurial, and I have found it very easy to set up and to use for personal use. As @Ignacio says, you can set up the repository in your project directory. You can also set up consolidation repos to manage across projects, and to keep track of multiple different approaches on different projects.  Setting up a new repository and populating it takes less than a minute. The learning time for this system was minimal too.

Answer (score 0):

I do software development mainly on the Windows platform. Thus I use VisualSVN to help me keep my repositories on my home network storage (or on the local computer storage) acting as the server, and I also use TortoiseSVN to access local SVN - acting as the client.

This allow me to work on small local projects which is easy to maintain.